# Multiple CSS sheets - Container div background is not on top?

Tags: css, html

I'm giving new life to a boring web page.  Please see what my template should look like here: [Correct body page](http://www.carrollconcrete.com/img/sustainability_news.html) 
Pretty page!

Now - when I go to add my existing background / menu/ footer - I am somehow loosing my container image -

```
/* structure */
.container {
background: url(/img/bgcontainer.gif) repeat-y;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 702px;
position:relative;
}
```

I removed position:relative; (but it still failed).  Please note I'm having to use a web content manager only because I have no other access to site. For this reason - my css sheet is in the middle of the page.
This is how the page looks now w/missing bgcontainer.gif:
[Current page](http://www.carrollconcrete.com/pages/Sustainability)

Please help - thank you

Comment: the links return `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Not sure what happen to you Sotiris?? The gentleman below found the links with no problems.  I was so happy to hear from all of you - except the advice given is still not working - any other takers??

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) I can see that the html structure of the two pages is quite different. On the "good" one you have a ".container" div as a wrapper of most of the content, you can see it here with the black border:

[image]

But on the "wrong" one you have a "#container" div in the same position and another ".container" div further down, nested inside that "#container", and it wraps that header only.

[image]

The "#container" div of the "wrong" page spans the whole witdh.

By the way, I like your design.

EDIT:
This is the look of the page with `float: left;` and `left:107px;` added to the ".container" div.

[image]

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply - (site page w/menu) sorry if I do not understand 1st container is the web content manager - which I cannot change. 2nd div container is my html??  <div id="container"> I do not see a  <div id="#container">. Can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry mine says   <div class="container"> class not id

Comment: Yes, sorry, my naming conventions where not very good! In the page with url "http://www.carrollconcrete.com/pages/Sustainability" you have this html: [...]<body><div id="container">[...]

Comment: yes <div id="container"> at the top using style sheet /css/screen.css"  My <div class="container"> is in the middle using img/default.css

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. As far as I can see, the problem of the .container div not spanning vertically to wrap all the nested elements (visually) is because of the floats. It contains floated elements, but the .container is not floated, so it "stops" when the first floated element is encountered (.main), just as you can see in the screeshot. If you float it, you will see your background, although you will get other layout problems.

Comment: what about setting a specific height to the 2nd container?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on the specifics of the page, but I wouldn't go that way because you would be styling your elements with a specific content in mind, what if the content changes and the height is not enough?

Comment: Please see my edit above for a possible solution, although again, it very much depends on the needs of the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your biggest problem:

The structure of the HTML pages is MUCH too different to pin this problem on one single line of code. In the "old" page there are 5 stylesheets including your own; in the "new" page there is only one stylesheet.

The reason your old and new pages don't look the same when you add your default.css stylesheet is because the old page has FOUR other stylesheets also applying styles, many of which are overriding your own.

Comment: yes - I do realize that Moses - hence my reason for writing a script for background image override. The only thing missing is the side navigation - I'm just trying to do my best, because I cannot change old style sheets. I only wanted to make the page - new and different from the rest.

Comment: My point was if you're trying to integrate your stylesheet into an old page, your development page should be an exact copy of your live page (in other words, you should add those 4 stylesheets into your test page so you will know how they affect the code you write).

Comment: yes - I did that first. That is why I am here - I cannot solve this one problem...